# How to replace function calls in binary files with self implemented malloc?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, hook

My code is written in C/C++. I want to replace the original call with my own implemented `malloc` function without modifying the code or recompiling. It seems that `LD_PRELOAD` can do this thing, but it can only be used for dynamic linking situations. As far as I know, the libraries used for the binary files I need to modify are all statically linked, so it may not have any effect.

There is a method for hot patching through ftrace in the kernel. Is there a similar function in user mode?

Comment: Wait? Did you statically link against glibc? There's a warning not to do that.

Comment: I would try `LD_PRELOAD` first just in case.

Comment: Look at the symbol table of the executable: `readelf -s ./myprogram` You can use `grep` or just scroll the output in an editor. If the `Ndx` field for (e.g.) `malloc` is `UND`, then `libc` is _not_ statically linked

Comment: @CraigEstey I got `14` for `malloc`. So it seems `libc` is statically linked.

Comment: But `sbrk@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)` and `mmap@GLIBC_2.2.5 (3)` are both `UND`. Since they are used to support malloc, could I try to hook these two functions?

Comment: _without modifying the code or **recompiling**_ This implies you _do_ have the source code and _can_ recompile/relink. It's generally _not_ a good idea to statically link `libc`. If `malloc` is statically linked and `sbrk/mmap` are _not_, this implies that the given program is linked with a custom `malloc` already (e.g.) `void *malloc(size_t size) { void *ptr = sbrk(size); ... } int main(void) { char *ptr = malloc(23); ... }` Thus, you probably can _not_ use the `malloc_hook` functions. The best/easiest way may be to recompile and use `LD_PRELOAD` to inject your functions.

Comment: If you _must_ patch, you could load _your_ `malloc` using `LD_PRELOAD`. You invoke the target program from a program you write that runs the program under `ptrace` (similar to `strace`). Your program will have to read in `/proc/pid/maps`, the executables (via `libelf`) so you have all symbol info. You can locate the address of the "offending" `malloc`. Then, you can replace the first inst with (e.g.) `jmp my_malloc` dynamically in memory, just the way `gdb` might when inserting a breakpoint. It's a lot of work to do all the symbol munching, but, if you _insist_ ...